# Factorio: Cannot Finish Steam Engine Campaign Mission

Tags: factorio

I started playing Factorio and I am at the campaign mission where the steam engines are introduced.

It asked me first to build a pump and pipes to the boiler which I did. I also put coal into the boiler. Then it asked me to build pipes to the steam engine, which I also did. However, from there on nothing happened. It still asks me to build pipes to the steam engine, which are there already, filled with water, and there are the yellow "no power" triangles on all appliances except the boiler.

When I put in coal into the boiler, it heats up briefly but then stops again.

The message in the corner, that I need to connect pipes to the steam engine, does not go away.

I have no idea how to move on from there. Any clues?

[image: Screenshot from Factorio]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you see the pipe that goes straight up from the boiler? There exits the steam. You need to connect this part to the boiler, and also make sure coal is added. The way it is seen in your picture, it only passes cold water to the steam engine.

On the [Wiki Page](https://wiki.factorio.com/Boiler), you can see the symbols for water and steam and where they connect. If i remember correctly, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key is used to toggle the information view.

Comment: I guess the tutorial probablly hasn't been updated to explain this behaviour (which is new in 0.15) yet.

Comment: @PeterGreen, yep, boiler mechanics changed in 0.15, while tutorials not. This is a source of this problem.